# How Rest api's are working without including certificates in Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

I am invoking some third party REST APIs using Jersey2, it's working fine, the API's are "HTTPS", so I am wondering how they are working since I didn't included any certificates in my code? As per my knowledge, certificates are necessary for HTTPS, can anyone guide me on this? Below is my code:

```
    HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("username", "password");
    Client client = ClientBuilder
            .newBuilder()
            .property(LoggingFeature.LOGGING_FEATURE_VERBOSITY_CLIENT, LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY)
            .property(LoggingFeature.LOGGING_FEATURE_LOGGER_LEVEL_CLIENT, "INFO")
            .build();

    client.register(feature);

    WebTarget target = client.target(<HTTPS URL>);
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData = new MultivaluedHashMap<String, String>();
    formData.add("Name1", "VALUE1");
    formData.add("Name2", "VALUE2");
    Response postResponse =
            target.request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .post(Entity.entity(formData,MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE),
                        Response.class);`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it uses java `cacerts` shipped with jdk, check in $JDK_HOME/jre/lib/security , java client will use this certificate to establish secure connection if not overridden with custom certificates.